# Logical, arithmetical bitwise shifts

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Seeking to clarify something.

It is my understanding that with regard to arithmetical, logical bitwise shifts:

1. `<<` work the same for both
2. `>>` shifts differ in that logical shift will always pad byte with 0, whereas arithmetical shift will pad it with the sign bit.

How can I differentiate this using C?

From what I understand, actual operators are the same `<<`,`>>`

How would command differ between:

```
int i=1;
printf ("%d\n", i >> 1); // logical shift

int j=1;
printf ("%d\n", j >> 1); // arithmetical shift
```

Please let me know,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case of nonnegative numbers, both kinds of right-shifts are the same. The difference appears only when the number to shift is negative.

Actually the C standard does not specify when should `>>` perform logical or arithmetic shift when the number is negative, but typically, it performs arithmetic shift. To perform logical shift, the number must be cast to the corresponding unsigned type, [for example](http://www.ideone.com/UbNrG):

```
int x = -2;
int y = x >> 1;    // arithmetic shift.
assert (y == -1);
int z = (unsigned)x >> 1;  // logical shift.
assert (z == 0x7FFFFFFF);
```

Comment: Is there a way to force a particular shift. For instance, i'd like to (x<<1)>>1 in order to drop the "-" sign.

Comment: @mac: Discarding the sign bit isn't the same as taking the absolute value in two's-complement.

Comment: @jamesdlin . totally. don't know what i was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: @KennyTM: yup, much improved.

Comment: can you give me an example of arithmetic shift. I'm a bit confused.