# arithmetic shift

Tags: objective-c, bit-shift

what is the difference between logical right shift and arithmetic right shift?

Comment: None of your previous questions have had a satisfactory answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical, arithmetical bitwise shifts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703000/logical-arithmetical-bitwise-shifts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arithmatic right shift duplicates the sign-bit.  Logical shift ignores the sign bit and the left-most bit becomes `0`.

**Example**

8-bit right-shift to keep things simple.

Example 1

`11100101`  Original bits
`11110010`  Arithmetic right-shift
`01110010`  Logical right-shift

Example 2

`00011101`  Original bits
`00001110`  Arithmetic right-shift
`00001110`  Logical right-shift

Note that both operations are the same when the sign bit is `0`.

Comment: can you explain through some example

Comment: @Shweta: Examples added.  Please accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: What is the purpose of arithmetic right shift. I am still not getting its purpose

Comment: Arithmetic shift is, as it's name suggests, used is arithmetic operations.  An arithmetic right shift divides by 2 while maintaining the sign of the operand.  For unsigned integers you need to use a logical shift.  For positive signed integers, a logical or arithmetic shift will do the trick.  For negative signed integers you need to use arithemtic shift to get the right answer.

Comment: As a general rule you use logical shift for unsigned arithmetic, and arithmetic shift for signed arithmetic.

Comment: I think a MAJOR fact to note is that both operations are the same effect when the sign bit is '0'

Answer (score 3):

LSR shifts the bits to the right and fills the MSb with 0. ASR shifts the bits to the right and fills the MSb with whatever was there before the shift, which preserves the "divide by 2" mechanism for signed numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One (arithmetic shift) preserves sign (by filling in the vacated left-most bit position with a duplicate of what was previously there); the other does not (logical shift) and instead always fills in with zeroes.